# "Add -> Load Test" Missing from VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a load test but the button is missing. I am able to create a performance/load test project however.

[image: Menu]

What I've done:

**VS Enterprise 2019 16.0.4**

- Search everything
- Create empty solution w/ only tests
- Web and Load Testing module is installed

[image: web performance module]

- Repair VS2019
- Re Install VS2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS 2019 Right Click -> Add -> Load Test has been removed

Instead Add -> New Item -> Test -> Load Test

[image]